# Cancel both events of jquery accordion

Tags: jquery-ui

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#accordion").accordion({
            change: function (event, ui) {
                alert('control changed')
            },
            changestart: function (event, ui) {
                alert('control changing')
            }
        });
        $("#accordion").bind("accordionchange", Change);
        $("#accordion").bind("accordionchangestart", ChangeStart);

        function Change(e, ui) {          
             // code for canceling both  events
            alert('bind:changed')
        }
     function ChangeStart() {  
            // code for canceling both  events              
            alert('bind:changing')
        }
    })
```

How to cancel both events via new bind event

Answer (score 0):

<del>I would suggest preventing the default behavior:</del>

<del>`function Change(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function ChangeStart(e) {

        e.preventDefault
    }`</del>

<del>If that doesn't work you can unbind the events, though this would be a pain to re-bind:</del>

This should be what you're looking for:

```
$('#accordion').unbind("accordionchange").unbind("accordionchangestart");
```

Comment: this doesnt work because remove only new (bound) events. The events that i declare inside accourdion are still there

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to disable the header navigation on click event

```
 $("#accordion h3").unbind("click");
```